# Divolte clickstream not working with ReverseProxy

Tags: apache-kafka

I've set-up a divolte clickstream script on a page which gets consumed by `kafka`.

The setup works when I host divolte scripts using `http` but when I source scripts via `https` and set up a reverseproxy in `.htaccess` to send requests to a `http` URL, `kafka` doesn't consume any content.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: How did you try to consume messages from Kafka? You need to share some code.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous it's probably the reverseproxy issue in .htaccess file. The param values are not getting passed to the `http` URL. Any ideas on fixing it? You may refer this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53259079/how-to-define-mod-rewrite-rule-to-pass-multiple-parameters